# Starting services

Tags: android

I've only just really started android developing and have been reading about services [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html). I've created a service which I then try to start in an activity, but I cannot work out why it will not show the toast notifications.

I've got the following activity:

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Example extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MService.class);
        startService(intent);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

and in my manifest I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:label="example" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="Example"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    <service android:name=".MService" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

and then my service looks like this:

```
package com.example;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MService extends IntentService {

public MService() {
    super("MService");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Systems starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

I know your not really mean to override onStartCommand but this was more as testing exercise since I also tried without

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service was a child of activity in the manifest so it couldn't find the service.

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the order of your lines within `onStartCommand` - assign the `super` call to an `int` variable, pop your Toast then return that var.  Even if this doesn't work, it's the preferred way of overriding methods.

Comment: Did you try putting it in an overridden `onCreate()` method?

Answer (score 0):

you can directly start the service class from activity by using this single line of code.

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyService.class));
```